# When $f/\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ does not depend upon $x$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, rational-functions

Suppose that $f(x,y,\ldots)$ is a multivariable non-constant *rational* function. When $f/\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ does not depend upon $x$?

**My attempt**: The question equivalent to when
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(f/\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\equiv0
$$
that is
$$
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2\equiv f\cdot\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}
$$
Is this equation solvable? I know that if $f$ is a single variable function, then the solution of $(f')^2=ff''$ is $f=Ae^{Bx}$, so $f$ is not rational.

Comment: For sure the equation holds for any function $f(x,y, \cdots)=f(y,\cdots)$ that doesn't depend on $x$

Comment: @Marco, for such a function, the $x$ partial would be zero. But you can't divide by zero so the original expression probably shouldn't count as something that doesn't depend on $x$. But you're right for the differential equation, of course.

Comment: Your ODE shows (fixing the remaining variables) that the function cannot depend on $x$. So the original question is not well-posed.

Comment: Thanks @Ted Shifrin. So the answer for the original question is "never" and my proof for single variable holds for multivariable just by fixing the remaining variables?